# Rank of a a linear operator $f^n$.

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $f$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$. If $n$ is a positive integer, let $f^n=f\circ f\circ...\circ f$ ($f$ written $n$ times).

a) Show that rank$(f^{n+1})\leq$rank$(f^n)$.

b) Show that if $m$ is a positive integer such that rank$(f^m)=$rank$(f^{m+1})$, then rank$(f^m)=$rank$(f^{m+k})$ for all positive integers $k$.

I assume b would be answered once I get the proof for a, but what I think of proving a is thru a mathematical induction (with the use of the rank-nullity theorem) which I think is exhausting. Is my hunch right, or is there another way of proving this? Send help. Hints would be much appreciated, I still want to prove this items on my own so I won't mind if you don't give me the direct proofs for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. You can use the rank-nullity theorem, but not for a proof by induction. You just have to use the fact that $\ker(f^n)\subset \ker(f^{n+1})$ (which is true because of the linearity of $f$).

Comment: Thank you Sir, but I think I missed something. Why is it that ker$(f^n)\subset$ker$(f^{n+1})$ because of linearity of $f$?

Comment: $f^{n+1}=f\circ f^n$, so if $f^n(v)=0$ for some $v\in V$, then $f^{n+1}(v)=f(f^n(v))=f(0)=0$, with the last equality holding because linear functions map $0$ to $0$.

Comment: Can I use my proof in a to prove b?

Comment: No need. It follows from a slightly stronger result: if $Im(f^m)=Im(f^{m+1})$ then $Im(f^m)=Im(f^{m+k})$ for every $k\in\mathbb N$. This is proved using that $Im(f^{n+1})\subset Im(f^n)$ for every $n$, so when $rank(f^n)=rank(f^{n+1})$, you have the equality. 

Then you need to prove from that equality that $Im(f^{n+1})=Im(f^{n+2})$ (hence $Im(f^n)=Im(f^{n+2})$). You already have one inclusion, as earlier. The other one, $Im(f^{n+1})\subset Im(f^{n+2})$, is done using the previous equality.

Once you have done this, the result follows directly from induction.